# Git при каждом коммите требует "Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary"

Tags: git

Есть удалённый репозиторий на bitbucket. Я коммичу на него с локальной машины, потом с удалённого сервера запрашиваю изменения. Локально пользуюсь TortoiseGit, если что. Репозиторий простой как двери, никаких веток, просто коммиты один за другим. В какой-то момент поставил галку "Amend last commit", потом забыл снять и так и запушил. С этого момента на удалённом сервере начались какие-то грабли. Для начала слетела регистрация, пришлось заново заводить ник и емейл. После этого вроде стало нормально, но при каждом git pull origin master он выводит мне в текстовом редакторе сообщение:

```
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

я уже вводил туда разное, сохранял, а он не унимается. Каждый pull сопровождается этим запросом. Что ему надо, и что вообще вдруг могло сломаться от безобидного "Amend last commit"?

Comment: Посмотрите историю коммитов в древовидном виде - будет поучительно...

Comment: приложите вывод `$ git status`

Comment: *"поставил галку "Amend last commit", потом забыл снять и так и запушил"* -- git отказался бы "так запушить". Уверены, что он действительно запушил?

Comment: www@site:~/sites/fidea$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
локально и на удалённом сервере

Comment: @PavelMayorov http://take.ms/EjmUI всё линейно

Comment: @D-side, не знаю ) не помню уже на каком именно комите это произошло. Но так или иначе все изменения в репозитории.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на той машине, где вы получаете предложение сделать слияние («merge»), история изменений в локальном хранилище отличается от той, что наличествует в промежуточном хранилище (на сервере bitbucket.com) и в хранилище на вашем рабочем компьютере.

посмотреть отличия в истории можно, например, так (выполнять на той машине, где вы получаете предложение сделать слияние):

```
$ git log origin/master...master
```

посмотреть отличия в содержимом файлов можно, например, так:

```
$ git diff origin/master...master
```

---

чтобы перестать регулярно делать слияние:

если эти изменения вам нужны, их надо отправить в промежуточное хранилище

```
$ git push
```

если не важны, можно от них отказаться, переставив указатель («ветку», «branch») на тот же коммит, куда указывает `origin/master`:

```
$ git reset origin/master
```

Comment: Помогло. Но почему вдруг появилась рассинхронизация? Как это можно выяснить? Добавлю, что удалённый сервер может только получать коммиты, на push у него нет прав.

Comment: вы сделали коммит на этой машине. и никуда его не отправили. вот и «рассинхронизация» истории. как выяснить, что это был за коммит и что в нём было изменено — я написал в ответе.